# How to store token from another api in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my DJango application I use another API external to my application.
To authenticate on the external API, I must first make a POST with my credentials, and get a JWT token.
Once this token is retrieved, I have to put it in the headers to be able to make requests on the api.

Once the token is retrieved (thanks to requests), how to store it in a "global" way to be able to reuse it until it expires  ?

Comment: If the backend environment is not cleared in between. IMO, Environment Variable can do the job for you. Set the env. on the token getter and access the env. var for preceding requests to make.

Comment: It can depend a lot on your environment - if you have only one server running you can keep in memory though this solution does not scale at all. My first choice would be to store the token in a store - Redis as retrieval is quite fast but if you don't have it deployed already you can create a Django model for the token and store it there.

Comment: Completely agree with @Mihai :+1: